# How to format data to the given format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Currently I am passing Json data as

```
coords: [
  {lat: 27.17841526682381, lng: 73.29395468749999}, 
  {lat: 24.88842099751237, lng: 73.64551718749999}
]
```

Instead of this, I need to send Json data as

```
 coords: [
    {27.17841526682381, 73.29395468749999},
    {24.88842099751237, 73.64551718749999}]
```

How can I able to achieve the same. How can I obtain these result.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I think you might be missing a "{" at "[27.17.." change it in that way and you would be sending an object with an array of cords that have no properties. It would work but your code would then have to always assume the first value in the object is a lat and the second is a lng.

Comment: I tried using for loop

Comment: post the  server side  code.

Comment: Model is designed as  border      : [[]],

Comment: So I need to pass accordingly

Comment: `I need to send Json data as` so, you don't want to send JSON data at all,just some randomly formatted data - neither of those blocks of data are valid JSON anyway

Comment: @Bravo How can it be?

Comment: @coder Your desired output format is incorrect, becaus ethe inner `objects` are invalid objects, they should be `arrays`, take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185530/3669624) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a very simple `map()` operation

```js
const coords = [
  {lat: 27.17841526682381, lng: 73.29395468749999}, 
  {lat: 24.88842099751237, lng: 73.64551718749999}
]

const res = coords.map(o => [o.lat, o.lng])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) as a callback:

```
coords = coords.map(Object.values);
```

**Note:**

Note that your desired output format is incorrect because the inner `objects` aren't valid `objects`, they should be `arrays`.

**Demo:**

```js
let coords = [
  {lat: 27.17841526682381, lng: 73.29395468749999}, 
  {lat: 24.88842099751237, lng: 73.64551718749999}
];

coords = coords.map(Object.values);
console.log(coords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... use `Object.values()`

```js
var coords= [
  {lat: 27.17841526682381, lng: 73.29395468749999}, 
  {lat: 24.88842099751237, lng: 73.64551718749999}
]


let items = [];
for (var prop in coords) {

 var val= Object.values(coords[prop]);
 items.push(val)
}
console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your output should be a nested array like:

```
[[27.17841526682381,73.29395468749999],
[24.88842099751237,73.64551718749999]]
```

You can use `reduce` on your array of objects to achieve this in the following way:

```js
var coords = [
  {lat: 27.17841526682381, lng: 73.29395468749999}, 
  {lat: 24.88842099751237, lng: 73.64551718749999}
];

var formattedCoords = coords.reduce((dict, item) => [...dict, [item.lat, item.lng]], []);

console.log(formattedCoords);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce